# Not able to create desired array from 2 table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 tables as shown below

student

```
id  student_name
1      S1
2      S2
3      S3
4      S4
```

teacher

```
id    teacher_name
1       T1
2       T2
3       T3
```

class

```
id   student_id   teacher_id
1       1             1
2       2             1
```

I want the result array to be like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [student_id] => 1
            [teacher_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [student_id] => 2
            [teacher_id] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [student_id] => 3
            [teacher_id] =>
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [student_id] => 4
            [teacher_id] =>
        )
)
```

The query that i am using is

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
  ->from('class')
  ->join('student', 'student.id = class.student_id', 'left')
  ->join('teacher', 'teacher.id = class.teacher_id', 'left')
  ->get();
```

The result that i am getting inside the array is

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [student_id] => 1
            [teacher_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [student_id] => 2
            [teacher_id] => 1
        )
)
```

Can anyone please tell what changes i need to do to get the desired result

Comment: Is it in codeIgniter?

Comment: @B. Desai yes it is

Comment: check wayneOS 's answer it will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should join the students and teacher-table over the class-table. But i did not test this.

```
$query = $this->db->select('student.id, teacher.id')
  ->from('student')
  ->join('class', 'class.student_id = student.id', 'left')
  ->join('teacher', 'teacher.id = class.teacher_id', 'left')
  ->get();
```